# How to give fixed height for Angular JS Auto Complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angular

ng2-auto-complete result goes lengthy. If I try to inspect and give some css, when a click is done, results are gone. Then I tried one sample like below,

```
ng2-auto-complete{
height: 400px; 
overflow-y: scroll; 
overflow-x: hidden;   
}
```

I think it's working for me, but a scroll was always in the mentioned height. How to solve this bug. Are there any other methods?

Check out the below result, that scroll was always there.

Check the image below

[image]

Check the Code below

```
<div _ngcontent-c14="" class="form-group">
    <label _ngcontent-c14="">Language
        <span _ngcontent-c14="" class="required">*</span>
    </label>
    <div _ngcontent-c14="">
    <div class="ng2-auto-complete-wrapper" style="position: relative;">
        <input _ngcontent-c14="" class="form-control ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty" display-property-name="TextField" name="ng2autoLanguage" ng2-auto-complete="" placeholder="Enter your language" value-property-name="ValueField" ng-reflect-klass="form-control" ng-reflect-ng-class="" ng-reflect-name="ng2autoLanguage" ng-reflect-source="function () { [native code] }" ng-reflect-display-property-name="TextField" ng-reflect-list-formatter="function (data) {
           " ng-reflect-model="" ng-reflect-ng-model="">
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to provide a sample, add your codes then only we can check it and help you.

Comment: Ok sure @EmadDehnavi

Answer (score 0):

Try using `max-height`:

```css
ng2-auto-complete {
    max-height: 400px; 
    overflow-y: scroll; 
    overflow-x: hidden;   
}
```